# Android Tabs in 3 lines

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I have 4 tabs and i trying to make 9 tabs in 3 lines 4;4;1 I don't know how do it and I can't find a solution to this problem

[image]

my code:

```
public class TablesFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.tables_fragment);

Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A"),
    NewsFragment.class, arg1);

Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("B"),
        NewsFragment.class, arg2);
Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
arg3.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 3);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("C").setIndicator("C"),
        NewsFragment.class, arg3);
Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
arg4.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 4);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("D").setIndicator("D"),
        NewsFragment.class, arg4);

return tabHost;
}
}
```

Comment: why do you want this type of UI? `Tabs` are not supposed to have multiple rows

Comment: what would you advise me

Comment: It depends on what your app flow is. You might want to re-think your UI.